# Como importar en mongodb con upsert?

Tags: mongodb, insert, importación

estoy usando mongodb y tengo una tabla con dos llaves:

```
db.dbname.createIndex({col1:1, col2:1},{unique:true})
```

Estoy importando un CSV y quiero que dependa de la combinación de dos llaves, para insertar o actualizar.
Por las pruebas que he realizado, tengo 10 filas con la primera columna igual pero la segunda es diferente y me inserta solo una y me la actualiza como la ultima fila, es decir no coge la combinación de las dos llaves.

```
mongoimport --db xxxxx --collection xxxxxx --authenticationDatabase xxxx --username xxxxxx --password xxxxxx --type csv -d xxxxx -c xxxxxx  --headerline --upsert --upsertFields 'col1, col2' ".$csv_destino.""
```

Estoy haciendo algo mal? o hay otro método para hacer esto?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la versión de MongoDB que estas usando? Saludos

Comment: @g.4 La versión 4.4.3 Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato tienen la columna 1 y la columna 2 en el CSV? Asumo que la colección Mongo también tiene registros, y quieres reemplazarlos con los del CSV, por eso estas tratando de hacer un `upsert` ¿Hay alguna columna id en el CSV? cuando dices que la primera columna con 10 registros, de tu CSV es igual, ¿te refieres a que los 10 registros CSV son los mismos que hay dentro de alguna llave de tus documentos? y cuando realizas la operación tienes como resultado, solo la inserción de la primera columna del CSV, y esta posicionada como la ultima llave para cada uno de los 10 documentos.

Comment: Si pudieras agregar estos detalles editando la pregunta, así como un ejemplo mínimo de cómo se ve tu CSV y como quieres que se vea tu documento después de la operación  `upsert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema es el comando actual que estás usando para hacer el proceso de importación. Actualmente tienes lo siguiente:

```
mongoimport --db xxxxx --collection xxxxxx --authenticationDatabase xxxx --username xxxxxx --password xxxxxx --type csv -d xxxxx -c xxxxxx  --headerline --upsert --upsertFields 'col1, col2' ".$csv_destino.""
```

Hay cosas repetidas, por ejemplo:

```
--collection xxxxxx
-c xxxxxx
```

La opción [`-c`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/index.html#cmdoption-mongoimport-collection) es una abreviatura (*shortcut*) de `--collection`, según muestra la documentación:

> `--collection=<collection>, -c=<collection>`

Lo mismo aplica para la opción `-d` y `--db`

En cuanto a la opción `--upsert`, no es correcta, no existe dicha opción en las listadas en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/index.html#cmdoption-mongoimport-mode), lo correcto sería una de las siguientes formas:

```
--mode upsert
--mode=upsert // <- esta forma es preferible
```

Además, tienes mal la forma en que pasas los campos `col1` y `col2` a la opción de `--upsertFields`. Actualmente lo tienes así:

```
--upsertFields 'col1, col2'
```

La forma correcta debería ser:

```
--upsertFields=col1,col2
```

Nótese que no se usan comillas simples o dobles, de lo contrario MongoDB asumirá que el campo por el cual quieres hacer el `upsert` se llama: "col1, col2" (¡todo junto!).

Por último, sugiero que indiques el nombre del archivo `csv` usando la opción [`--file`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/index.html#cmdoption-mongoimport-file), ya que esto te permitirá ser más explícito en el comando que estás ejecutando. Esto es sólo una sugerencia, ya que la sintaxis admite especificar el nombre del archivo como último argumento del comando `mongoimport`:

```
mongoimport <options> <connection-string> <file>
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es escribir el comando de importación de la forma correcta:

```js
// siempre es preferible usar el operador de igualdad para evitar confusiones
mongoimport
  --db=xxxxxx
  --collection=xxxxxx
  --authenticationDatabase=xxxx
  --username=xxxxxx
  --password=xxxxxx
  --type=csv
  --headerline
  --mode=upsert
  --upsertFields=col1,col2
  --file=data.csv
```

Como puedes observar, cada opción que requiere una asignación usa el operador de asignación (=).

Si prefieres usar la sintaxis sin la opción `--file`, también sería válido de la siguiente forma:

```js
mongoimport
  --db=xxxxxx
  --collection=xxxxxx
  --authenticationDatabase=xxxx
  --username=xxxxxx
  --password=xxxxxx
  --type=csv
  --headerline
  --mode=upsert
  --upsertFields=col1,col2
  data.csv
```

De esta forma, se actualizarán los documentos existentes, cuyos campos `col1` y `col2` coincidan con los datos del archivo `csv`. Si no hubiera documentos existentes en la colección, se añadirían nuevos a partir del archivo `csv`. Los conflictos de unicidad de índices compuestos, se resolverán sin problemas, insertando o actualizando sólo aquellos documentos que cumplen la restricción de unicidad en los campos `col1` y `col2`.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias @Mauricio Contreras , lo voy a revisar a ver si me funciona.